Install/Compile Python polars on ARM64 (Windows)
I have an ARM machine (Snapdragon X Elite) on Windows. So tried pip install polars but ran into a few issues.
Issue 1
failed to run custom build command for `ring v0.17.8`
warning: ring@0.17.8: Compiler family detection failed due to error:
    ToolNotFound: Failed to find tool. Is `clang` installed?
    (see https://docs.rs/cc/latest/cc/#compile-time-requirements for help)

As per https://github.com/briansmith/ring/blob/main/BUILDING.md I installed Visual Studio 2022 with both

MSVC v143 - VS 2022 C++ ARM64/ARM64EC build tools and
C++ Clang Compiler for Windows

and then added C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\VC\Tools\Llvm\ARM64\bin to my PATH environment variable, so that clang.exe could be found.
Issue 2
error: failed to run custom build command for `libz-ng-sys v1.1.20`
failed to execute command: program not found
is `cmake` not installed?

So I added C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin to PATH as well, so that cmake.exe could be found.
Issue 3
Still failing on libz-ng-sys, this is the final error:
error: failed to run custom build command for `libz-ng-sys v1.1.20`
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Preview/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.30/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:67 (message):
  The C compiler
    "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Preview/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.43.34604/bin/Hostx64/arm64/cl.exe"
  is not able to compile a simple test program.


Is there a way to fix the last issue, and use polars on ARM on Windows somehow?
(the full log can be found here: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/19960)

Instead of describing issues 1 and 2 which you have resolved in the past, you are better to provide the complete error message for that last case, The part you show is continued with "It fails with the following output:", after which the error from the compiler itself is printed.

@Tsyvarev I wanted to provide full context as it did not work out of the box.

Cmake should have produced a log file with the actual error message. Edit your question with that.

I was able to install the polars library using this command:
pip install polars

